How to prefetch external JSON and use it?
I want to prefetch (or maybe preload) a JSON file from an URL and use it later on my JS file. How can I send the prefetched JSON to the JS file?
Something like on the HTML head:
<link rel="prefetch" href="https://json.file" as="fetch">

or on the JS file:
fetch("the prefetch file above")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
  });


you can use this
<link rel="prefetch" href="/data.json" as="fetch">

by this instead of going to the server again and ask for the file when you want to use it, the browser will load the resource from the cache.
fetch('/data.json')
    .then(response => {
    // some code
    })
    .then(json => {
        // some code
    })
    .catch(console.error);


Thanks for your answer!
Can I do that even if the prefetch is loading an external resource? Like: 'href="www.somewebsite/data.json"'

yes any link to an accessible file will work
